# Message queue for cross thread sync

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, thread-safety

```
public class WmSync : IDisposable
{
    public WmSync()
    {
        var sync = new Control();
        sync.Handle.GetHashCode(); // ensure handle is created
        _sync = sync;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _sync.Dispose();
    }

    public void BeginInvoke(Action action)
    {
        _sync.BeginInvoke(action);
    }

    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        _sync.Invoke(action);
    }

    public bool InvokeRequired
    {
        get { return _sync.InvokeRequired; }
    }

    private readonly Control _sync;
}
```

The idea is to create this object in the main thread and use it from background threads to execute pieces of code in the main thread.

For example:

```
// somewhere in the very beginning of the program, in the main thread
static WmSync SyncQueue = new WmSync();

// somewhere in a background thread
SyncQueue.Invoke(
    () =>
    {
        if (_settingsForm != null)
            _settingsForm.Show();
    });
```

This is just an artificial sample, but it should give you idea. Is this code thread safe?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `The idea is to create this object in the main thread and use it from background threads to execute pieces of code in the main thread` by updating your question. Some real world example would help also.

Comment: @Heslacher, done. And BTW, it's not a threadsafe UI control.

Comment: I have reverted the title change.

Answer (score 1):

**Thread.MemoryBarrier()**

What do you expect the call to `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` will help your code ?

What does `Thread.MemoryBarrier` do ? It prevents that the compiler and the hardware subtly transform a program’s memory operations.

So basically for your code it ensures that then following instructions will be executed in the order they are written.

> ```
> var sync = new Control();
> sync.Handle.GetHashCode(); // ensure handle is created
> _sync = sync;
> ```

**Thread safety**

To answer "Is this code thread safe ?", you first need to set your definition of thread safety aka what does thread safety means for you. See also [what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe)

**General**

- the code is lacking a `EndInvoke()` which should be integrated.
- you are misusing a `Control` to access the main (ui) thread of an application.
- wouldn't a [`SynchronizationContext`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=net-5.0) be a better fit here ?

  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20300351/2655508

Comment: in the first place, this class was never supposed to be used in UI. The idea is to pass execution to the main thread, it's the one and only function of this class.

Comment: "2. you are misusing a Control" - in the same way everyone (including MS) does. "3. wouldn't a SynchronizationContext be a better fit here" - how exactly?

Comment: @user626528 if it's not a UI application, then what is the definition of "main thread" then? Why can't you run your logic in the "background" threads? Please describe why you need to capture a certain thread and name it "main"